# Excel Conditional Formatting Based on Another Cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to make an excel-sheet for the university, where every course for each season is listed, and whenever a grade in a specific range is entered, the corresponding rows (season, course, ECTS and Grade) needs to be highlighted in green.

The range is

> 1 ≤ Grade < 5

So far I have tried the following formula, which results in an error:

```
=AND($D2 >= 1, $D2 < 5)
```

This is how the sheet looks like:

[image: How it looks like ath the moment]

Error:

[image]

[image: Formula in use]

[image: Format-Manager]

Comment: what error do you get.  That formula should work.

Comment: This is the error message 
https://filestore.community.support.microsoft.com/api/images/c50a1eb6-8231-41e1-802d-5ef918806a3e

Comment: Does your local settings use `;` instead of `,`?

Comment: Changing `,` to `;` indeed removed the error message, but it still doesn't highlight the columns.

Comment: can you [edit] your post to include a picture of the conditional format manager?

Comment: The language might be in German, but I hope it goes without explanation.

Comment: The only thing I can think of then is that your numbers are stored as text and not true numbers.  That would be the only reason I can see why it would not work.

Comment: I just change the formatting of the Grades to number, still won't work :(

Comment: If they are stored as text merely changing the cell format will not work, try:  `=AND(--$D2 >= 1, --$D2 < 5)`

Comment: Oh, I see. I tried your solution, but unfortunately it doesn't work either.

Comment: Then I am out of guesses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your excel is in German, have you tried using "UND" instead of "AND"?

Comment: That actually worked out, such a simple solution.  Thank you Mario!